# javascript functions are callbacks mandatory

Tags: javascript, function

If I have a function like this

```
function foo (arg1, arg2, callback) {
  // blah blah
  callback()
}
```

can I just do:

```
foo (arg1, arg2)
```

Sometimes I find that I can't, what's going on here? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand. Are you talking about a particular library? or are you talking about JavaScript in general?

Comment: That depends very much on the details. Arguments are all optional in Javascript always, callbacks being no exception. What is this "sometimes" you refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue is that `callback()` will throw an error if you only pass in two arguments since it's effectively doing `undefined()`

If you are writing the function, you can do:

```
callback && callback()
```

meaning that it's only called if it exists (for more of a failsafe, check that it's a function).

If you don't control it, you can pass in an empty function:

```
foo(arg1, arg2, function(){});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't pass a third parameter to foo, "callback" will have a value of "undefined".    Hence, you'll likely hit a script exception when you get to the invocation of the callback() function.